# Unity+PlayFab c# sequential execution

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

Please advise on C# syntax, I am doing Rest API Call toward PlayFab to get a player profile and then get assign the player display name to a local public variable, BUT during execution the sequence of function I found that they are not sequential at all. I don't understand why, as in python or java, all function is sequential and they will be executed after another function has completed.

By the logic, it should execute start function with **OnLoginWithGoogleAccountPlayFab** which will call **GetPlayerProfile** fetch the player name and assign on a public string **PlayerDisplayName**, then call ChangeSceneOnNewPlayer which will check for name if it is null.

But it executes this way [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPscC.png)

```
public PlayerDisplayName;
void Start(){
        OnLoginWithGoogleAccountPlayFab();
}
public void OnLoginWithGoogleAccountPlayFab() {
        PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithGoogleAccount(new LoginWithGoogleAccountRequest()
        {
            TitleId = PlayFabSettings.TitleId,
            ServerAuthCode = AuthCode,
            CreateAccount = true
        }, (result) =>
        {
            PlayFabId = result.PlayFabId;
            SessionTicket = result.SessionTicket;
            Debug.LogWarning("waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrrr- --------------------- GET PROFILE 1");
            GetPlayerProfile();
            Debug.LogWarning("waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrrr- ---------------------NAME 1 ");
            ChangeSceneOnNewPlayer();
        }, OnPlayFabError);
    }

public void GetPlayerProfile() {
        PlayFabClientAPI.GetPlayerProfile(new GetPlayerProfileRequest()
        {
            PlayFabId = PlayFabId,
            ProfileConstraints = new PlayerProfileViewConstraints()
            {
                ShowDisplayName = true,
            }
        }, (result) =>
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrrr- ---------------------PROFILE 2");
            Debug.Log("The player's DisplayName profile data is: " + result.PlayerProfile.DisplayName);
            PlayerDisplayName = result.PlayerProfile.DisplayName;
            Debug.LogWarning("waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrrr- ---------------------PROFILE 3");
        }, OnPlayFabError);
    }

public void ChangeSceneOnNewPlayer() {
        Debug.Log("Player Info");
        Debug.LogWarning("waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrrr- ---------------------NAME 2 ");
        if (PlayerDisplayName == null) {
            Debug.Log("Player Info is NULL " + PlayerDisplayName);
            Debug.LogWarning("waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrrr- ---------------------NAME 3 ");
            SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("New_Player", LoadSceneMode.Single);
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Player Info NOT null " + PlayerDisplayName);
            Debug.LogWarning("waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrrr- ---------------------NAME 3 ");
            SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("City", LoadSceneMode.Single);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please remove the Java tag. This question has nothing to do with Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods *are* being executed sequentially, but the results you get back are returned asynchronously. This introduces race conditions to your code and is the reason you see the `ChangeSceneOnNewPlayer` method being executed before you have received the player profile.

Let's break down what's happening in the following lines (debugging removed for clarity):

```C#
// Both these lines execute synchronously.
PlayFabId = result.PlayFabId;
SessionTicket = result.SessionTicket;

// Here you're invoking a synchronous method, but inside the method
// an asynchronous call is made to PlayFab, and the result will not be immediately
// returned.
GetPlayerProfile();

// Then you immediately call this method, but you haven't waited for the result from 
// PlayFab before you make this call.
ChangeSceneOnNewPlayer();
```

What you want is something more like this:

```C#
public PlayerDisplayName;

void Start()
{
    OnLoginWithGoogleAccountPlayFab();
}

public void OnLoginWithGoogleAccountPlayFab()
{
    PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithGoogleAccount(new LoginWithGoogleAccountRequest()
    {
        TitleId = PlayFabSettings.TitleId,
        ServerAuthCode = AuthCode,
        CreateAccount = true
    }, (result) =>
    {
        PlayFabId = result.PlayFabId;
        SessionTicket = result.SessionTicket;

        // Get the profile, and specify a callback for when the result is returned
        // from PlayFab.
        GetPlayerProfile(OnGetPlayerProfile);
    }, OnPlayFabError);
}

public void GetPlayerProfile(Action<PlayerDisplayName> onGetPlayerDisplayName)
{
    PlayFabClientAPI.GetPlayerProfile(new GetPlayerProfileRequest()
    {
        PlayFabId = PlayFabId,
        ProfileConstraints = new PlayerProfileViewConstraints()
        {
            ShowDisplayName = true,
        }
    }, onGetPlayerDisplayName, OnPlayFabError);
}

// This method is used as a callback to your GetPlayerProfile function and is used
// to process the information.
public void OnGetPlayerProfile(PlayerDisplayName playerDisplayName)
{
    PlayerDisplayName = playerDisplayName;
    if (PlayerDisplayName == null)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("New_Player", LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
    else
    {
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("City", LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
}
```

This is a standard pattern when using any RESTful API calls.

Comment: Hi Aaron

What, if I want to reuse GetPlayerProfile function?

Comment: @vinilka8 There's nothing stopping you from reusing it. The `GetPlayerProfile` method is asynchronous by nature, so you'd just have to account for that with the rest of your code. It is possible to cache values, so you could save the `PlayerDisplayName` and access that later. However, you can run into problems if you do that. Imagine you cache the `PlayerDisplayName` value, but then they change their profile information. You'd want to make sure you refresh that data when that happens, otherwise you'd be displaying a "stale" value to the user.

Comment: Hi @Aaron, thanks for explaining, sorry was not clear in my question, I would love to use GetPlayerProfile function for something else, If I will call it again I will be dealing with switching the scenes again but I don't want this happen. Only at the beginning.